# How to turn dbt logs OFF?

Tags: logging, dbt

We're using `dbt 0.19.1` for our data transformation stuff.

Number of tables transformed are 100+ ones.

Once triggering `dbt run`, we get lots of log line saying as:

```
08:42:58 | Concurrency: 10 threads (target='DEV')
08:42:58 | 
08:42:58 | 1 of 167 START incremental model a [RUN]
08:42:58 | 5 of 167 START incremental model b [RUN]
08:42:58 | 9 of 167 START incremental model 
...
```

It is annoying in PRODUCTION so that I'm searching for a way to turn it off there.

I've read the [dbt document](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/introduction) as such but can't find an option.

Anyone has any ideas please? Appreciated!

Comment: Ollie had a good answer. But why would you want to turn off logging in production? Wouldn’t you want to know if something goes wrong?

Comment: @AndersSwanson: It isn't really important for those running log. We only need to know if success or failure, and the error message when it failed in Production.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think dbt allows log suppression through the CLI. One way to get around it would be to pipe the output, e.g. `dbt run > /dev/null`

Comment: Thanks Olle. This is a good solution. But I'm using dbt as python module, and triggering dbt run by calling the function: handle_and_check. Any chances with that to turn off the log?

Comment: @DatNguyen it's likely possible, but running dbt through the Python API is [quite heavily discouraged](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/running-a-dbt-project/dbt-api), and not documented, so the only way to find out would be digging through the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Olle's anwser is officially the right one.

Another work around solution is to use Python API - which NOT DOCUMENTED, and NOT RECOMMENDED once you'd upgrade dbt version.

```
from dbt import main

# pre stuff

# main show
if log_disabled:
    main.log_manager.disable()
res, success = main.handle_and_check(args=YOUR_ARGS_HERE)

# post stuff
```

How to create a hook by using dbt as module, let's check out [the repo named `airflow-dbt`](https://github.com/gocardless/airflow-dbt/blob/04f660ae1e04bbdc58e328de43218cf9a031f739/airflow_dbt/hooks/dbt_hook.py#L76)